# how to find maximum value in a web table column using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

There are four columns in Web Table.. 'Version', 'Downloads', 'Name', 'Last Accessed on'.

So if i want to get the version no which has maximum (value) of download in Download column.

How to achieve that using selenium.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store elements in the List :

```
    List<WebElement> myList=driver.findElements(By.className("acc-toggle"));
    //To store all web elements into list

    List<String> all_elements_text=new ArrayList<>();
    //If you want to get all elements text into array list

    for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++){

        all_elements_text.add(myList.get(i).getText());
        //loading text of each element in to array all_elements_text
        System.out.println(myList.get(i).getText());
    }
```

Then you can print the maximum number using Collections API as follows :

```
Object obj = Collections.max(all_elements_text);

System.out.println(obj);
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
static int max=0;

static String version = null;

List<WebElement> storeRows = storesTable.findElements(By.cssSelctor("table tr"));

for(int i=0; i<storeRows.size();i++{

WebElement columnValue = storeRows.findElement(By.xpath("\td[3]"));

WebElement versionElem = storeRows.findElement(By.xpath("\td[1]"));

if(Integer.parseInt(columnValue.getText()) > max){

   version = versionElem .getText();
   max = Integer.parseInt(columnValue.getText());
    }

}

System.out.println("For Vrsion " + version + " are the highest downloads = " + max);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read version and corresponding downloads count from web table. Below code does that:

```
    // Below line will get column headers and rows of webtable
    List<WebElement> cols = driver.findElements(By
            .xpath(".//table/thead/tr/td/div"));
    List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By
            .xpath(".//table/tbody/tr"));

    Map<String, Integer> records = new HashMap();

    // Add version column data into an array list
    String version = "";
    int downloadCount = 0;
    for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows.size(); rowCount++) {
        List<WebElement> rowCells = rows.get(rowCount).findElements(
                By.tagName("td"));
        for (int count = 0; count < cols.size(); count++) {
            // Get version into list
            if (cols.get(count).getText().contains("Version")) {
                version = rowCells.get(count)
                        .findElement(By.tagName("div")).getText();
            }

            // Get downloads into list
            if (cols.get(count).getText().contains("Downloads")) {
                downloadCount = Integer.parseInt(rowCells.get(count)
                        .findElement(By.tagName("div")).getText());
            }

            records.put(version, downloadCount);
        }
    }
```

Next you need to find the maximum download count. Using stream concept you can get that as below:

```
    // This will get max download value
    Optional<Entry<String, Integer>> str2 = versions3.entrySet().stream()
            .max(new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1,
                        Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                    if (o1.getValue() > o2.getValue()) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            });
    // Max download value
    System.out.println(str2.get().getValue());
    // Corresponding versionid
    System.out.println(str2.get().getKey());
```

Suppose if there are more than one record with same download count(maximum value) then below code will fetch all the versions. Need to manipulate the string to get versionid.

```
    //If there are more than one version with same downlaod value (Max) then below code will fetch all versions
    List<Object> str4 = versions3.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == str2.get().getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(str4);
```

Hope this helps.